# onclick JS not executing in ie8/9 problem

Tags: javascript, html

I have this line:

```
<input class='submit_img' type="image" onclick='ax_update_mood();' src="/images/rainbow/gobuttonbluesmall.png" value="Submit" alt="Submit"></td>
```

...then I have this JavaScript:

```
function js_alert() {
    alert('TEST ALERT');
}

function ax_update_mood() {
    var str_mood_desc = $('#moodmeter_form_mood_desc').val();
    var str_mood_color = $('#moodmeter_form_mood_color').val();

    if (str_mood_desc.length < 3 || str_mood_desc.length > 32) {
        alert('Mood Description must be between 3 - 32 characters long.');
        return
    }

    if (str_mood_color.length < 1 || str_mood_color.length > 32) {
        alert('Mood Color must be between 3 - 32 characters long.');
        return
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "moodupdate",
        data: "mood_desc=" + str_mood_desc + "&mood_color=" + str_mood_color,
        success: function (msg) {
            ax_get_mood();
            alert("Mood Updated ");
        }
    })
}
```

When I click on the "submit," my JavaScript does not execute.

Can some one explain please?

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any errors to the developer tools console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provided that the code you quoted for `ax_update_mood` is at global scope (not contained within another function), I can't see any reason it wouldn't run. It may well not have the effect you intend, though, because nowhere are you preventing the submission of the form when your validation fails. To do that, you have to change the `onclick` part to:

```
onclick='return ax_update_mood();'
```

...and you have to `return false;` when you want to cancel the form submission.

Separately, because you're using an ajax call to do the work, you want to `return false;` even when the validation *succeeds*. Otherwise, the form will get submitted and your ajax call will never happen.

Your best bet with things like this is to use the built-in debugger ("F12 Developer Tools"), enable debugging, set a breakpoint on the first line of `ax_update_mood`, and walk through the code, seeing where it's going wrong.

Just to make my point about it being global explicit, your code as written *has* to be at page-level scope:

```
<script>
function ax_update_mood() {
    // ...
}
</script>
```

**not** within something else, like this:

```
<script>
jQuery(function($) {
    function ax_update_mood() {
        // ...
    }
});
</script>
```

...because the `onclick` attribute can only address global functions.

Rather than making it a global function, though, since you're already using jQuery, I'd probably change the `input` to look like this:

```
<input class='submit_img' type="image" id="btnSubmit" src="/images/rainbow/gobuttonbluesmall.png" value="Submit" alt="Submit"></td>
```

...and then put all of my code within the jQuery `ready` callback (just so I don't create global functions or variables; global scope is already plenty crowded enough):

```
jQuery(function($) {

    // Hook the click event on the image button
    $("#btnSubmit").click(ax_update_mood);

    function js_alert() {
        alert('TEST ALERT');
    }

    function ax_update_mood() {
        var str_mood_desc = $('#moodmeter_form_mood_desc').val();
        var str_mood_color = $('#moodmeter_form_mood_color').val();

        if (str_mood_desc.length < 3 || str_mood_desc.length > 32) {
            alert('Mood Description must be between 3 - 32 characters long.');
            return false;
        }

        if (str_mood_color.length < 1 || str_mood_color.length > 32) {
            alert('Mood Color must be between 3 - 32 characters long.');
            return false;
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "moodupdate",
            data: "mood_desc=" + str_mood_desc + "&mood_color=" + str_mood_color,
            success: function (msg) {
                ax_get_mood();
                alert("Mood Updated ");
            }
        });

        return false; // Even on successful validation, we don't want the form to submit
    }
});
```

---

**Somewhat off-topic**: Some miscellaneous notes:

- In many places, you're relying on the horror that is *automatic semicolon insertion*. Always make sure **you** terminate your statements with semicolons, never rely on the JavaScript interpreter to understand your meaning well enough to do it for you. I've fixed them in the last example above.
- Since you're clearly using jQuery, I'd suggest hooking up your validation with jQuery on DOM load rather than using the antiquated `onclick` attribute means of doing so. I've shown how to do that in the last example above as well.

Comment: my js is in a seperate rainbow.js file

Comment: what i have done now is to rather put the javascript code in my .php file as you suggested but still nothing happens when i click on the go/submit button??

Answer (score 0):

Do you have IE configured to alert you on script errors?  If this works in FFX or Chrome and not IE you may want to enable errors for all client scripts and see where the choke point is.  You can find the script notification settings in Tools-->Internet Options-->Advanced, scroll to the Browsing heading and check the "Display a notification about every script error."  You'll also want Script Debugging enabled, which is one of the checkboxes in very close proximity to the script error notification.

Another thing you can do to track the problem in IE is insert a debugger statement.  Just update ax_update_mood() so that the first line is the word "debugger":

```
    function ax_update_mood() {  

        debugger;

        var  str_mood_desc = $('#moodmeter_form_mood_desc').val();  
        var  str_mood_color = $('#moodmeter_form_mood_color').val();   

        // ... the rest of your code 
    }
```

Then use IE to step through the method and see where your failure is.

The only other thing I can see is you might need a semi-colon after your .ajax() call.  I've noticed that IE8 will choke on object/jquery notation where semi-colons don't terminate the declaration.

Any additional troubleshooting assistance would require more detail on how you're referencing JQuery, what the rest of the page looks like, etc.

Happy coding.

B